# Gradle how to publish a gradle-plugin to maven central

Tags: maven, gradle, gradle-plugin, publishing

Hi I have a java project, which contains a submodule which is a gradle plugin. I want to publish this module to maven central.

I used this two plugins in my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
  id 'java-gradle-plugin'
  id 'maven-publish'
}
```

and my `publishing` block looks something like:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        javaLibrary(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact sourcesJar
            artifact javadocJar

            artifactId = project.archivesBaseName

            pom {
                name = artifactId
                description = "..."

                url = 
                licenses {
                    license {
    
                    }
                }
                developers {
                   ...
                }
                scm {
                   ...
                }
                issueManagement {
                   ... 
                }
                ciManagement {
                   ...
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories { maven { url = "some local repo" } }
}
```

I noticed that when I build this module, the generated `pom-default.xml` is what I expected, but when I run `gradle publishToMavenLocal` and manually checked the `pom.xml` file in the `.m2` folder, all the metadata like `name` `description` `licenses` are gone!

I also noticed in the `.m2` folder there are 2 artifacts that are related to this single plugin, I think it's somewhat related with https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_markers but I don't fully understand the meaning. Both these 2 artifacts' pom are missing the pom metadata as I described above.

Could some gradle expert help me here: how to keep the metadata in the published pom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not need to manually define a `MavenPublication` for your plugin submodule. The `java-gradle-plugin` reacts to the application of the `maven-publish` plugin and automatically configures/creates publications for the plugin artifacts. See [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v7.0.0/subprojects/plugin-development/src/main/java/org/gradle/plugin/devel/plugins/JavaGradlePluginPlugin.java#L214) line.

You are correct for the (2) artifacts produced. One is the plugin marker (single `pom.xml`) and the other is the actual plugin JAR artifact.

As for POM customization, Gradle seemingly provides its own the POM irrespective of any POM customization(s) you have defined: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/17022

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer, but you can do something like this:

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.withType(GenerateMavenPom) { task ->
        doFirst {
            // Update POM here
            def pom = task.pom
            pom.name = ...
            pom.url = ...
            pom.description = ...

            pom.scm {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will catch the pom of the plugin marker artifact as well.